# ReferenceError: cloudSky is not defined, when trying to use csZbar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use this plugin: [csZbar](https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar)

The problem is if i follow what is written in the github repository like this:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){

$scope.newTask = function() {

cloudSky.ZBar.scan({}, function(succcess){ 
  console.log(success);
 }, function(error){
  console.log(error);
 })  
};

});
```

the error log says:

> ReferenceError: cloudSky is not defined

The csZbar is already included in the plugins folder. 
I'm totally new to Ionic.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Please update if you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I tried to run the app on desktop browser before run on ios.
It doesn't work if you simply run `ionic serve`, you must run it on ios itself.